# How can I restore lost data after executing the xfs_repair command to forcibly clear log files to restore the file system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, xfs

I already know how to do `xfs` meta data backup. To repair the `xfs` file system, only the `xfs_repair -L lv` command is available. I will move the abnormal Inodes to the `lost+found` directory after I want to perform the repair. Would you like to ask if there is any way to use `lost+found` backup for data combing to reduce the amount of lost data? Or are there better ways to reduce data loss?

Comment: Use *data* backups, perhaps?